# calling FB.login() in FB.logout() callback function

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have to check the FB user is the user who logged in my app,
my idea is that call login() in logout() callback function using javascript

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
  if(response.authResponse){
    FB.logout(function(r1){
      FB.login(function(r2){
        ...
        ...
        ...
      },{scope:"..., ..., ..."});
    }); 
  }
});
```

It can logout successfully. But after I log in, the log in dialog doesn't close.
I've try to set auth_type to re-authenticate, but reauth dialog cannot logout if the FB user isn't correctly.

I'm using URL to logout in some cases. but not suitable for all.

Anyone has idea for login function in the logout callback function?